# How to handle return value of a function?

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a subprocess call function which I need to handle the return value properly. For example, I have tried to use try/except but not quite sure it's the right approach or is there any better way to handle returned value. The bash script (pair.sh) is used for bluetooth pairing. If pairing fails, then pair.sh return pair fails and this function should handle the return value at that point.

```
def unpair(bd_addr):
    try:
        subprocess.call(
        "timeout 10 " + test.sh + " " + bd_addr,
        shell=True
        )
    except:
        print "test script fails to run"**
```

Comment: Unless you have an object called `test` with an attribute called `sh` calling `test.sh` will always result in an `AttributeError`. And thus your subproccess will never be called. Or a `NameError` for that matter if `test` is not defined either.

Comment: Exactly what to you mean by "returned value"?

Comment: test.sh is actually the bash script pair.sh or unpair.sh which use for pair and unpair the bluetooth devices.  pair.sh will return either pairing failure or success.  So how do I handle this return value from the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (python3+):

```
from subprocess import run, CalledProcessError

def unpair(bd_addr): 
# if your script called test.sh, use:
    try: 
        run("timeout 10 test.sh {}".format(bd_addr), shell=True, check=True) 
    except CalledProcessError as ex: 
        print("test script fails to run. Return code: {}".format(ex.returncode))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the return code from the shell script, you can use the return value from subprocess.call, something like this:

```
def unpair(bd_addr):
    returncode = subprocess.call(
    "timeout 10 " + "test.sh" + " " + bd_addr,
    shell=True
    )
    if returncode != 0:
        print "test script fails to run"
```

Comment: Thanks Jim.  This is probably the simplest solution since I'm still using python 2.x